# React router 6 side-effect clean-up on unmount

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a problem with react-router after I migrated to v6. The problem is when a router is used to render components that do side-effects and should do clean-up on unmount. In the v6 case, I don't get the component to run its clean-up function. I assume this is by design, but I would like to know how/can I model the v5 logic in v6.

I have two minimal apps that show my issue:

- **v5**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-xz5dvi?file=src/App.tsx ▶️ Switching between paths unmounts the previous component and then renders the new component. It looks like this:
  [image: v5]
- **v6**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-xz5dvi-tz4vuo?file=src/App.tsx ▶️ Same app in v6 where the previous component doesn't unmount and the behavior when switching between components is not working as is. It looks like this:
  [image: v6]

In both apps, the idea is that when you navigate to a page, it renders a component that modifies the DOM and removes the DOM elements it adds on unmount. This doesn't happen in the v6 case and the added DOM elements are kept in the DOM and they start to stack up:

Comment: I see both stackblitzes produce identical console logs, I'm unable to reproduce.

Comment: Really? I added a picture of the page when you click between links in the v6 version and the components start to add up. The behavior is different from v5 that removes the last visited component when routing to the next.

Comment: Affirmative. Just checked again, still see identical output from both.

Comment: Well, that's odd. I added two gifs to show what happens when I run both of the apps.

Comment: Are you ever looking at the *actual* console log instead of this jumbled UI? The logs there appear to be exactly the same when I run your sandboxes. I see no reason why a `useEffect` cleanup function or routing would work so differently. Additionally, direct DOM mutations are very anti-pattern in React, so they shouldn't be used as the yardstick for any sort of React performance comparisons.

Comment: Sure I understand that. I think I found the problem.

Comment: I think the issue is more to do with the React component tree and what/where the created DOMNodes are attached/removed to/from than it does React hooks and component lifecycle.

Comment: Yes. The clean-up targets a component that isn't in the DOM tree after reconciliation. Unmount cleanup is fired after this. The reason v5 doesn't make the UI go bonkers is just a coincidence. That version's implementation probably does something in the background to remove stuff inside the router.

This question spawned from a much more complex app I have which has a similar problem and I tried to replicate it minimally. I think I can fix my main app now as well.

Comment: The "fix" to this is actually now trivial: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-xz5dvi-ilpzig?file=src/App.tsx. Give the DOM element you create in the side-effect an ID, so it can be reliably targetted on the clean-up and removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't do `Imperative` work with React `Declarative` structure, it might bite you some times like this, (and ofcourse by imperative I mean adding innerText in `useEffect`).

A few points here to note are:

- it's not about `react-router` you're using React `useEffect` and it's calling you're `effects` and `clean up` functions the same ( as you can see by checking the `console` and seeing that `modifying` and `unmounting` are the same between two projects.
- the second point is your `cleanup` function, besides `console.log('unmounting: ', name);`, it doesn't do anything, because in both projects the `container` is `null`.

```
const container = document.getElementById(name); //container is null
container?.parentNode?.removeChild(container);
```

the difference between the two projects is that in v6 we use `Outlet` component and it's keeping the `text` that you're adding imperatively.

but if you were to use any other `effect` which needs an `unsubscribe` or `cleanup` you can do it perfectly in both versions.

in summary, both versions are working fine but the way you are adding or removing text is wrong, you could try other ways like showing or hiding a text based on a state which is more Reacty

Answer (score 2):

`useEffect` with dependencies should run its cleanup after the render, so it's actually proper behavior.

To run cleanup on unmount, use `useEffect` with an empty dependencies array

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    // Side effect where we modify dom
    console.log('modifying: ', name);
    const element = document.createElement('span');
    element.innerText = `This text was added as a side-effect for component: ${name}`;
    const container = document.getElementById(name);
    container?.appendChild(element);

    // Clean-up on unmount
    return () => {
      console.log('unmounting: ', name);
      const container = document.getElementById(name);
      container?.parentNode?.removeChild(container);
    };
  }, []);
```

But if you want to achieve same (invalid) behavior as with react-router v5, you have to force router to unnecessarily re-mount same component every time its prop is changed.

This is not recommended but here you go:

```
const pages = [...Array(3).keys()].map((x) => (
    <Route
      key={`route-${x}`}
      path={`component-${x}`}
      element={<Component key={`component-${x}`} name={`component-${x}`} />}
    />
  ));
```

(unique `key` prop will force react to not reuse same component)

### Explanation to `useEffect`:

1. `useEffect` always runs after a render
2. previous `useEffect` is always cleaned up before running new `useEffect`

So the first is render, then `useEffect` with new dependency value wants to run, so the previous `useEffect` with old value must be cleaned up.

### Example

```
interface FooProps {
  id: string
}

const Foo: React.FC<FooProps> = ({ id }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ id })

    return () => {
      console.log({ id })
    }
  }, [id]);

  return <div id={id} />
}
```

Order of events when this component is used:

1. `id` starts as `'a'`
2. div with id `'a'` is rendered
3. `useEffect` runs with its dependency `id` set to `'a'`
4. Foo receives property `id` with value changed to `'b'`
5. div with id `'b'` is rendered instead of div with id `'a'`
6. `useEffect` runs cleanup with its dependency `id` set to `'a'`
7. `useEffect` runs with dependency `id` set to `'b'`

So to make this absolutely clear:

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    // This cleanup runs only on unmount
  }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    // This cleanup runs right before this useEffect runs with updated name value
  }
}, [name]);
```